# My JMenu Bar is not showing up

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jmenubar

My JMenuBar is not showing up when i run my App.
How can I fix this??

So when I run my JFrame I need to see my JMenuBar on top.

my Layout is **Null**

Code:

```
package view;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;


public class Home extends JFrame {

    private Container window = getContentPane();

    public Home(){
        initGUI();  
    }

    public void initGUI(){

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        setLayout(null);

        JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        menu.add(file);
        window.add(menu);



        pack();

    }
    }
```

Comment: unrelated, but important: never-ever do any manual sizing/locating (aka: null Layout) Don't forget to read and understand the tutorial referenced in the swing tag wiki - it'll answer such basic questions :-)

Answer (score 3):

- you not added `JMenuBar` to the `JFrame`
- use `setJMenuBar(menu);`

Comment: but i did: window.add(menu);

Comment: in this case JMenuBar doesn't returns PreferredSize, then its size is 0,0

Answer (score 1):

Instead of add(menu) call

- setJMenuBar(menu);

Also you better use SwingUtilities.invokeLater()